# Need to create a microsoft flow to trigger email based on the email address mentioned in the excel row

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, power-automate, send-email

I am working on an excel which contains Name, Amount, quantity, email address and a dropdown - Send Email - Yes/No. I am trying to build a microsoft flow where I want to trigger an email when a user selects 'Yes' from drop down Send Email. This email should go to the email address mentioned in that particular row.

Can anyone please suggest how do we do this in microsoft flow. 
Appreciate any kind of assistance. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to know that to work with Flow/Power Automate, data in your Excel files must be formated as tables. As Flow can only recognize tables in Excel.

Then you could use the trigger "For a selected row" in the flow, then add a condition to send the email if the column value is  equal to "Yes".
[image]

Comment: Hello Michael, Thank you for coming for help. :) Yes, the data in the excel file is in a table and this excel would be placed in onedrive.  which trigger should I use first to connect to the excel?

Comment: The "For a selector row" trigger. I've added the screenshot in my answer.

Comment: Hello Michael, I am using the trigger "For a selected row" as a trigger and then added a condition as suggested but it gives me an error saying "this flow cannot be triggered for testing" . Am I doing it incorrectly. Please suggest.